# How to Populate Xib in a different Class

Tags: iphone, ios

My Problem  goes like this??

```
I am having a class  addEditPatient.m and its Xib .

I wants to use the Same xib In Another Class Named patientview.m,
this patientview contain it own Xib and a button called Addpatient .

i wants to Display the addEditPatient.xib when add button is clicked in patientview class. 

i don't wants to push the view i want to add the subview to patientview.

if Possible can any one give a example ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you, this'll work, add in the addButtonMethod of the patientview class this code:

```
AddEditPatient *addEditPatient = [[[AddEditPatient alloc] init] autorelease];
[self.view addSubview:addEditPatient.view];
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you so such,Orus                                                 It works for me.